# change java version to build play app with activator

Tags: typesafe-activator

Is it possible to set java version for the play app build with activator

I have java 8 on my sytem and server is with java 6. I want to create build with java 6 from activator.
I tried to set JAVA_VERSION 1.6 in activator file but when its deployed on the server it gave class version error.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the location of the desired JDK before launching activator, that Java should be used.

Comment: Is it possible like maven or ant http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: you can set javacOptions as in example here http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Java-Sources.html